# dx11 Rendering to texture shows only clearcolor

Tags: c++, rendering, textures, render, directx-11

Im trying to create a game view for my game engine using ImGui framework,however when i try to render texture,there is only clear color displayed on the screen.

My plan

- Creating Render Target Texture(I think i done this part right(i think))
- Writing my scene into target texture(I presume this is where i failed,only clear color displayed on the screen,my test triangle not displayed)
- Crearting a shader resource view(I tested this and the next step via loading image from the disk,it shows no problem here)
- Display it on İmgui::Image()

Using render texture only clear color and Imgui Editor elements displayed on the screen when set back to normal rendering,my test triangle appears on the screen.

My Render Texture Creation

```
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc;
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;

ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));
textureDesc.Width = 1920;
textureDesc.Height = 1080;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

renderTargetViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

DLE_Graphics::CurrentGraphics->pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, pTargetTexture.GetAddressOf());


shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

DLE_Graphics::CurrentGraphics->pDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(this->pTargetTexture.Get(), &shaderResourceViewDesc, this->pResourceView.GetAddressOf());

// (re)-create the render target view
DLE_Graphics::CurrentGraphics->pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(pTargetTexture.GetAddressOf()));
DLE_Graphics::CurrentGraphics->pDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(pTargetTexture.Get(), &renderTargetViewDesc, pRenderTargetView.GetAddressOf());



// create the depth and stencil buffer
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC dsd;
pTargetTexture->GetDesc(&dsd);
dsd.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
dsd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
dsd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;

DLE_Graphics::CurrentGraphics->pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&dsd, NULL, pDepthTexture.GetAddressOf());
DLE_Graphics::CurrentGraphics->pDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(pDepthTexture.Get(), NULL, pDepthView.GetAddressOf());

// activate the depth and stencil buffer
DLE_Graphics::CurrentGraphics->pContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, pRenderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), pDepthView.Get());
```

My Rendering Code

```
const FLOAT clr[] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
    pContext->ClearRenderTargetView(pRenderTexture->GetRenderView().Get(), clr);
    pContext->ClearDepthStencilView(pRenderTexture->GetDepthView().Get(), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 0u, 0u);
    pContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, pRenderTexture->GetRenderView().GetAddressOf(), pRenderTexture->GetDepthView().Get());
    pContext->DrawIndexed(size, 0u, 0u);

    pSwapChain->Present(0u, 0u);
```

If anyone curious this is my swap chain description

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC description = {};
    description.BufferDesc.Width = 1920;
    description.BufferDesc.Height = 1080;
    description.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    description.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    description.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    description.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
    description.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    description.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    description.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    description.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT ;
    description.BufferCount = 1;
    description.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    description.Windowed = TRUE;
    description.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    description.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;
```

When i use my render texture and create a resource view and use ImGui::Image to show there is no image,not even clear color.If i use my image on the disk for the ImGui::Image it displays the image,i dont what im doing wrong here

Here's my imgui code

```
ImGui::Begin("Spectrum Observer");
    ImVec2 pos = ImGui::GetCursorScreenPos();
    //ImGui::Image(texture->GetResource(), ImVec2(512, 512)); // my image from the disk
    ImGui::Image(pGraphics->pRenderTexture->GetResourceView().Get(), ImVec2(512, 512)); // render texture 
    ImGui::End();
    ImGui::Render();
    ImGui_ImplDX11_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());
```

I appreciate every input possible,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the triangle rendering problem via changing ClearDepthStencilView() 0u to 1u

```
const FLOAT clr[] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f };
    pContext->ClearRenderTargetView(pRenderTexture->GetRenderView().Get(), clr);
    pContext->ClearDepthStencilView(pRenderTexture->GetDepthView().Get(), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1u, 0u);
    pContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1u, pRenderTexture->GetRenderView().GetAddressOf(), pRenderTexture->GetDepthView().Get());
    pContext->DrawIndexed(size, 0u, 0u);

    pSwapChain->Present(0u, 0u);
```

Appearently i was clearing the depth buffer to 0 which indicates all depth values nearest possiible which leads to failing ztest.